# How to post time value in database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to post date value inside my database but every time I try, the date is not coming, but the auto row is working.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?PHP
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("test") or die("Couldn't connect db!");

$times = $_POST['times'];

$id_time = date("d-m-Y",time());

    if($times) {

        $qry = "INSERT INTO test(id_date) VALUES('$id_time')";
        mysql_query($qry);
        header("Location: bbb.php");

    }

?>


<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">

    <input type="submit" name="times" />

</form>
<div><?php echo $id_time; ?></div>
```

Here is my SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `test`
--

INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `id_date`) VALUES
(1, '0000-00-00'),
(2, '0000-00-00'),
(3, '0000-00-00'),


--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `test`
--
ALTER TABLE `test`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=6;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very simple:
You code here: `$id_time = date("d-m-Y",time());`

> Please UPDATE THAT INTO;

```
$id_time = date("Y-m-d",time());
```

Your sql is ok. And I hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the format of date to **$id_time = date("Y-d-m",time())**.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use in sql, try: `CURDATE()`

Like this:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO test(id_date) VALUES(CURDATE())";
```